# Function should have a prototype while declaring in class

Tags: c++, oop

I have a string to be printed via a function. I am using turbo-c compiler.

While using procedural method I am able to do it from following code :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void strr(char name[]);
void main(){
   char name1[10];
   cout << "Enter name";
   cin >> name1;
   strr(name1);
   getch();
}

void strr(char name[]){
   cout << name;
}
```

But With oop method I am not able to print the string. My Code is :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class name{
   public: void strr(char name[]);
};

void main(){
   char name1[10];
   cout << "Enter name";
   cin >> name1;
   strr(name1);
   getch();
}

void name::strr(char name[]){
   cout << name;
}
```

With oop method I am getting error `Function 'strr' hould have a prototype`.

Comment: the strr function you are using is not the function inside the name class.

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns `int`. **Always**.

Comment: Also, prefer to use `std::string` for text rather than character arrays.  Arrays suffer from buffer overrun and are a pain to pass to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function is defined inside the class, you need an object/instance of the `name` class to invoke it :

```
name obj;
cin >> name1;
obj.strr(name1);
```

Alternatively, if you declare the function as static, then you can invoke it without a class-instance, since the function is a *class-function* :

```
class name{
   public: static void strr(char name[]) {cout << name << endl;}
};

...

cin >> name1
name::strr(name1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
name :: void strr(char name[])
{}